# Eclipse Change Project from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, version

So I have exported my Java game to a runnable `.jar` file. But when I run it, it is extremely slow, much slower than it is in Eclipse. From the research I did, I think this is because the project uses `Java 1.6`, but my computer runs `Java 1.7`.

I've been trying to convert the project to `1.7`, but I keep getting this:

[image]

[image]

And this error when I try to run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ragemage/src/Window : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Comment: Did you set the right path to your jre7 in Window > Preferences > Installed JREs (type jre in the search field) ?

Also, you may have to right click on your project, go to Properties, type compiler and set the compliance to 1.7. Finally, remove JRE 6 from the referenced librairies of your project.

Comment: I removed JRE 6 from the libraries, and it runs now. However, I still get extreme lag issues when I run it as a jar file. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to look into it a bit longer and then ask a new question if it still runs slow.

Comment: Use a profiler (`visualvm` is included in the JDK) and see what's taking so long.

Comment: @Kayaman How do I run a `jar` with `visualvm`? And I think there's just rendering lag because the game seems to be running, but the rendering is very choppy and laggy.

Comment: @sparklyllama You start your jar, then you run visualvm and attach it to the virtual machine.

Comment: @Kayaman Sorry, but what do you mean by "attach it to the virtual machine"?

Comment: Have you run visualvm yet? It's not that hard to use.

Comment: Oh, right, I just got it working. I can't really see what's taking so long... Could the problem be that the program uses Java 6, but my system is running Java 7?